# Run post deployment scripts without deploying everything else

Tags: database-project

Is it possible to run the post deployment scripts without deploying other changes? There are changes in the project that I don't want to deploy to the staging environment yet, but I do need to run the post deployment scripts to make sure seed data is inserted. Normally I could use schema compare for just deploying selected changes, but obviously I can't do that with the post deployment script.

Comment: Generate the script, copy that section, and run it?  I don't think you can choose not to deploy the schema changes, but you can get a script to use.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Just thought maybe there'd be a way to generate just the post deployment script since the schema compare lets you selectively generate scripts for everything else.

Comment: Maybe if you set it to ignore almost everything in your options, but I'll admit I haven't tried that.